# Disabling links on Email Forward

Tags: email, outlook, gmail, html-email

I am sending emails to users which includes a one-time authentication link. I am trying to develop a feature through which if a user forwards the email to some other user, the links should get disabled.

One way is to hide the link by using a style tag which is covered [here](https://litmus.com/blog/preventing-unsubscribes-in-forwarded-emails):

```
<style type="text/css">

blockquote .original-only, .WordSection1 .original-only {

display: none !important;

}

</style>

<p class="original-only">

Content to be hidden <a href="">Unsubscribe.</a>

</p>
```

Is there a better/standard way to achieve the same? I would prefer to keep the link visible but clicking on the link will take the user to my web where I can check URL params to validate if the email is original or forwarded.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it would work, but for a different reason - Office 365 can "probe" the link first to see if it points to anything untoward. Your server would register a hit, but it won't be coming from a user.

Answer (score 2):

A foolproof way forward is essentially not possible, although you may be able to do it with some success on some platforms. (There isn't even a way to target all email clients individually on a straight send--let alone on a forward!)

What happens when you forward an email is that the email will be re-rendered, often without the accompanying embedded CSS that you are relying on (it depends on the email client).

So the reference to the class would be lost, and your link would now *show* after a forward:

```
<p class="original-only">
Content to be hidden <a href="">Unsubscribe.</a>
</p>
```

Furthermore, I see what you are trying to do there, in predicting that a forward would add a blockquote or a style like WordSection - but not all behave predictably, or if they do, you can't target them. For example, Gmail will add a class that begins with something like "_m" (from memory), but although CSS can target that with an `[attribute^="value"]` selector, most email clients will ignore this 'advanced' CSS.

In fact, you may have more luck reversing this:

```
<style type="text/css">
blockquote .original-only, .WordSection1 .original-only {
display: block !important;
}
</style>
<p class="original-only" style="display:none">
Content to be hidden <a href="">Unsubscribe.</a>
</p>
```

I haven't tested it, but if you sent that to, say, Gmail (noting some Gmails are different from others, e.g. IMAP/POP accounts), which DOES support embedded CSS, you would see the unsubscribe link. But forwarding might just remove the embedded CSS and so the `display:none` would kick in and hide the link.

However, if you sent it Outlook desktop, which does NOT support embedded CSS (anything in `<style>...</style>`), it would hide the unsubscribe link by default, as well as keep it hidden on a forward (probably).

Results are likely to be all over the place.